# PHP form validation using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am developing an application in using php and mysql.I have written a javascript code for form validation but its working .

```
     function checkForm()
        { if(document.Form1.Gestational_age.value=="")
                {
                   alert('Please select an option for Gestational age in weeks ') ;
                   return false;
                }
            else if(document.Form1.PRBC.value=="")
                {
                    alert('Please select an option for PRBC transfusion ');
                    return false;
                }
            else if(document.Form1.milk_feeding.value=="")
                {
                    alert('Please select an option for Human milk feeding at both day 7     and day 14 of life');
                    return false;
                }
    }
   </script>

    <title>GutCheckNEC for infants < 1500 grams at birth Gephart,2012</title>

   </head>
   <body>

    <div><b>GutCheckNEC   for infants < 1500 grams at birth Gephart, 2012</b></div>
    <br>
    <form name="Form1" method="post" action ="Form1.php" onSubmit="return checkForm();">
        1.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp Gestational age in weeks&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
         <input type="radio" id="Gestational_age" name="Gestational_age" value="0-27"/>0-27
         <input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" value="28-31"/>28-31
         <input type="radio" name="Gestational_age" value=">32" />32
         <br>

        2.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp PRBC transfusion&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
        <input type="radio" id="PRBC" name="PRBC" value="Yes"/>Yes
         <input type="radio" name="PRBC" value="No"/>No
         <br>
        3.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp Human milk feeding at both day 7 and day 14 of life&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp
        <input type="radio" id="milk_feeding" name="milk_feeding" value="Yes"/>Yes
         <input type="radio" name="milk_feeding" value="No"/>No
         <br>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
    </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

This s the sample of my code.Could you please hel,why my javascript part is not working..

Comment: What is not working? Do you have any errors message?

Comment: No error message,but its not validating the data,if im leaving the fields empty then its not giving an alert message.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the validation function by this and try. This checks if the value has been set or not.

```
    function checkForm()
    { 
        if(!document.forms["Form1"]["Gestational_age"][0].checked && !document.forms["Form1"]["Gestational_age"][1].checked && !document.forms["Form1"]["Gestational_age"][2].checked)
            {
               alert('Please select an option for Gestational age in weeks ') ;
               return false;
            }
        else if(!document.forms["Form1"]["PRBC"][0].checked && !document.forms["Form1"]["PRBC"][1].checked)
            {
                alert('Please select an option for PRBC transfusion ');
                return false;
            }
        else if(!document.forms["Form1"]["milk_feeding"][0].checked && !document.forms["Form1"]["milk_feeding"][1].checked)
            {
                alert('Please select an option for Human milk feeding at both day 7 and day 14 of life');
                return false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: document.forms["Form1"]["Gestational_age"].value returns as undefined

Comment: @Arjun thanks for yor reply..it is validating the from ,but it is showing an alert box even if i m setting the value..(its not validating correctly)

Comment: @user1495220 Sorry, my bad. Need to check for every radio button. It'll work now.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an Example

```
<script>
function checkForm(){ 
if(Form1.Gestational_age[0].checked==false && Form1.Gestational_age[1].checked==false && Form1.Gestational_age[2].checked==false)
   {
      alert('Please select an option for Gestational age in weeks ') ;
      return false;
    }           
   else {
     return true;   
   }
}
</script>
```

I have done that for only the first set of Radio Button. Hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: I am happy that i was able to hep you. If thats what you were looking for, you can up-vote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get value of radio button like this:

```
document.Form1.Gestational_age.value
```

use it like this

```
var ages = document.getElementsByName('Gestational_age');
var ageIsChecked = false;
for (var i = 0, length = ages.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (ages[i].checked) {
        ageIsChecked = true;
    }
}
if (!ageIsChecked) {
    alert('Please select an option for Gestational age in weeks ');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply..but my requirement is to check if a radio is checked or not nd incase not then i have to display alert...

Comment: just changed code, you should radio values like above code for others, or use jquery, its easy to check value with one line: $('input[@name="Gestational_age"]:checked').val();

Answer (score 0):

Try , `Gestational_age` is name with array so you need to pass as `["Form1"]["Gestational_age"]` and also `checked` attribute to check radio button length that radio button is checked or not.

```
function checkForm()
{ 
    if(document.forms["Form1"]["Gestational_age"].checked == "")
    {
        alert('Please select an option for Gestational age in weeks ') ;
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.forms["Form1"]["PRBC"].checked == "")
    {
        alert('Please select an option for PRBC transfusion ');
        return false;
    }
    else if(document.forms["Form1"]["milk_feeding"].checked == "")
    {
        alert('Please select an option for Human milk feeding at both day 7     and day 14 of life');
        return false;
    }
}
```

**It will alert your validation as you want because i have tested.**

Comment: document.Form1.Gestational_age[0].checked only works to first item of radiolist

Comment: ya it was my fault i did mistake.